# Does a git repository know/keep track if it's being used as a submodule in other repositories?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I know that I can ask the submoduling repository which repositories it contains, but does the submoduled repository also know that it's being contained somewhere?

Context is that I want to have some files in repositories of their own, then have multiple main repositories import some of these files. Then ideally if I wanted to know how many main repos are using a particular file, i would ask the file instead of cycling through the main repos and checking.

I don't actually think this is the case, but want to verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Only superprojects know their submodules. But submodules don't know their superprojects.

You can ask [`git rev-parse 
--show-superproject-working-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---show-superproject-working-tree) in an instance of a submodule but the main submodule repository doesn't know in what superprojects it's used.